# how to set jSpinner default value?

Tags: java, netbeans, jspinner

I'm using a jSpinner to set the time with format "HH:MM" and it works fine.

My problem is I want to set my jSpinner to "00:00" when the window is activated, and once jSpinner is clicked I want the value to be changed to the "HH:MM" format. And I can't do it myself, the jSpinner value doesn't change it is still "00:00".
Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your are using a `SpinnerDateModel`, then the value that the `JSpinner` is managing is `java.util.Date`.  You need to create a `Date` instance which has it's hour/minute fields set to midnight

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

Date date = cal.getTime();
spinner.setValue(date);
```

To get the format the value from the `JSpinner`, you can use a `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String value = sdf.format(spinner.getValue());
```

> but how can I set it with "00:00" when the window is activated

Without more information, I'd suggest using a `WindowListener` of some kind, assuming that you're not creating the window each time.

Have a look at [How to Write a Focus Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) and [How to Write Window Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)

> And changed the value once clicked?

That's a little unclear, but you should just get the value from the `JSpinner` at the time you need to know what it is and format based on your needs.  The `JSpinner` should be taking care of formatting the value automatically (based on your settings) when the values is updated.

Having said that, I did need to make the "start" (or lowest value) `null` when I set up the model, which seemed to allow the spinner to update the time value

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

Date startTime = cal.getTime();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
Date endTime = cal.getTime();

System.out.println(startTime);
System.out.println(endTime);

// The Calendar field seems to get ignored and overriden 
// by the UI delegate based on what part of the field
// the cursor is current on (hour or minute)
SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel(startTime, null, endTime, Calendar.MINUTE);
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(model);
spinner.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm"));

spinner.setValue(startTime);
```

Comment: Yeah, but how can I set it with "00:00" when the window is activated? And changed the value once clicked?

Comment: The first part will depend on how you are establishing the window; the second part should be taken care of by itself

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer, thank you. I got an idea and that's a big help. :)